# MySQL - генерация скрипта таблиц из текущей базы данных

Tags: mysql

Как можно сгенерировать скрипт создания всех таблиц в бд MySQL?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Ну во первых сначала все равно придется ручками создавать. А вот потом для распространенияи переноса приложение конечно использовать SQL дамп базы